# How to see if a record with doesn't already exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Friendship` model which allows users to become friends with one another. The records for these `Frienships` has a `requesting_user_id` and an `accepting_user_id`. I want to build a method that checks to see that a record with the same accepting_user and requesting_user pair doesn't already exist. In short, that a one user has already befriended another user.

I started this in my `User` model:

```
def can_befriend?(accepting_user)
  @accepting_user = Friendship.find_by_accepting_user_id(accepting_user)
  @requesting_user = current_user
end
```

But I'm not sure how to check that the pair doesn't already exist. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use a dynamic cross-finder method that will search for both at the same time. It's a mouthful, but should work.

```
@old_friendship = Friendship.find_by_accepting_user_id_and_requesting_user_id(accepting_user.id, requesting_user.id)
if @old_friendship.nil?
    #create new friendship here
end
```

Comment: you could also use the find_or_create_... variant to ensure you get a valid friendship record back - either the old one, or a new one